height: 100% not streching to the whole parent
I put min-height: 100vh; on the body, then height: 100% on the main. For some reason, the main height does not stretch full to the parent.
https://codepen.io/pen/
Can somebody explain? Thanks.
I also tried adding other, but anything does not seem to work under the


body {
  border: 2px solid red;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

main {
   border: 2px solid green;
   height: 100%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
  <main>hihihihasidfiojdi</main>
</body>
</html>




A height in percent only works, if the parent element has an explicit height. Just a min-height won't work. But 100% of 100vh are still 100vh.

height does not inherit min-height value either ;) But if body is turned into a grid, then main will fill it up without the need to set height  example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mdYKdBb

Add main height as 100vh
main {
   border: 2px solid green;
   height: 100vh;
}


The issue arises because setting height: 100%; on an element only works if the parent element also has a defined height. In your case, the main has height: 100%;, but its parent, body, has a min-height set to 100vh, not a fixed height. This means that the height of body is not explicitly defined, and thus main cannot inherit 100% of it.
You can use flexbox on the body to ensure that main stretches to fill the remaining space.


html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    border: 2px solid red;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

main {
    border: 2px solid green;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body> 
  <main>hihihihasidfiojdi</main>
</body>
</html>




Change min-height: 100vh; to height: 100vh; in the body selector. If you specify a height in percent, there has to be an explicit height in the parent element (min-height will not set the height explicitly).
